# Using jndi with jpa and spring on glassfish

Tags: spring, jpa, glassfish, jndi

I have a web application that runs on glassfish 3.1. I am using JPA (Hibernate) configured with spring.
This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myPU">

        <class>org.myCompany.entities.Class1</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is part of my ApplicationContext.xml:

```
<tx:annotation-driven /> 
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/myDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPU" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In addition i have declared my datasource in the glassfish server (jdbc connection pool and recourse)
and the JNDI name is "jdbc/myDataSource". The issue is that on my local installation of glassfish, published via the glassfish plugin for eclipse, it works fine BUT when i deploy the war file manually on an installation of glassfish (i tried on my VPS - CentOS) then i get this error:

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused. Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.
```

For some reason, the application is using the default derby datasource of glassfish and not my defined datasource. anyone knows why and how to overcome this?

Comment: What was the solution for this? I'm getting this on a fresh glassfish install. I've clearly defined my datasource, but it's resolving it to __default.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure your JDBC Resource to use the right Connection Pool? There is a default derby pool configured. Maybe you just selected the wrong pool for your resource?